# What the worst thing that can happen if I write concurrently (from multiple treads) to an java.util.HashMap?

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

I have a C++ background from which I know that concurrent writing access to an `std::map` can have very unpleasant consequences, what is the situation in Java with `java.util.HashMap`?

Note that I would like to know whether there are bad side effects beside the obvious race condition.

As far as I understand `ConcurrentAccessException` is thrown only if you are iterating through a `java.util.HashMap` while you are modifying it from another thread, does that mean that it is safe to simply call the `get` method while another thread is calling `put` (with "safe" I mean that the worst thing that can happen is that you retrieve the wrong value)?

Is it somehow possible to cause a SEGFAULT in a similar a way?

Note that with "similar" I mean through race condition that only involves pure Java method/objects (no JNI stuff)

Comment: It can have very unpleasant consequences, but in general, only race conditions. You can get an intra-thread CAE as well. A segfault is relatively unusual in a VM language.

Comment: Yeah, an intra-thread CAE is probably the most common case (calling put on a map while iterating through it), but I'm interested only to the multithreading case now

Comment: A `ConcurrentModificationException` can also be thrown when you are iterating and modifying incorrectly on the same thread.

Comment: I'm asking because I'm working on a code base where this happen frequently but I am told that it is not a serious issue (and they are right if the worst side effect is the race condition)

Comment: One annoying thing is that, while in C++ it is trivial to write a simple program that tries to do this and blows up into very small pieces, Java seems very resilient and all the test cases I wrote just seem to work, resulting in nothing more than a race condition :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, never do that, wrap the map in a `Collections.synchronizedMap` which is easy enough.

The internal state could get corrupt, which could result in any of these:

[edit] two new items (the top two)

- Memory leak because keys get into the wrong buckets and can never be retrieved/deleted unless `clear()` is executed
- Infinite loops because of circular loops in hashtable buckets
- Items getting lost (they will be garbage collected if not used elsewhere)
- Items appearing twice for the same key (when iterating)
- Items linked to the wrong key
- (new) Iterators may barf unexpectedly
- If the map is a `NavigableMap` you may experience extra barfing

A hard error like a segfault cannot happen in Java because it's a 'safe' language and will throw a `NullPointerException` in similar situations.

Comment: You can get segfaults in Java apps, even w/o JNI. It's relatively unusual, but absolutely happens.

Comment: I thought they only happen when you get bitten by a JVM bug and they shouldn't happen normally (if not using JNI/JNA/`Unsafe` that is)

Comment: Of course it shouldn't happen normally--that's why they're called "exceptions" :)

Comment: @DaveNewton a segfault is very different from an exception, btw I'm not interested in segfaults caused by JVM's bug but in segfaults caused by bug in appplication code

Comment: @oggioniw As I stated in my comment a segfault is unusual, but the possibility of it being exercised by user code is not zero.

Comment: @DaveNewton could you provide an example without using JNI or `Unsafe` or without leveraging a JVM/native library bug? (it's pretty obvious that if I call my native library's function `crash` implemented with `*((int *)(NULL)) = 1;` I get a SIGSEGV)

Comment: @oggioniw Nope, they're unusual. In theory any time the jvm crashes it's a jvm bug, so I'm not sure what you're getting at there.

Answer (score 2):

The worst that can happen includes things like:

- expected runtime exceptions; e.g. CCME,
- unexpected runtime exceptions (NPE's etcetera),
- incorrect results; e.g. `get` returning the wrong value, `put` losing entries, or
- infinite loops (!).

I have seen reports of all of them.

The reason is that if the threads don't synchronize appropriately when using the shared `HashMap`, then there can be:

- problems due to overt race conditions, or
- problems due to one thread seeing stale values due to various (permitted) caching behavior.

> Is it somehow possible to cause a SEGFAULT in a similar a way?

No.  Or at least, not unless your codebase includes native code OR uses `Unsafe` OR it tickles a JVM bug.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's clearly unsafe and you should not even consider calling HashMap methods from different threads. Also in Java you probably won't face SEGFAULT as the one you can face in C and C++.

Instead of that you should consider using `ConcurrentHashMap`.